# Django Signals post_save that use foreign key

Tags: django, django-views

I am not yet very proficient in Django signals.

I just want that for every 6 new Entries Enter in **User**,  the first profile save in the **User_GraduateList** will automatic save in **GraduateUser**

Table **User**

[image]

table **User_GraduateList**

[image]

This is I want result in Table **GraduateUser**

[image]
since Joe Dio is the first Entry in **User_GraduateList**

This is my models

```
class User(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True,blank=True)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    middlename = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)

    Email  =  models.CharField(max_length=500,null=True,blank=True)
    Sponsor_User = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True, null=True)


class User_GraduateList(models.Model):
    User = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_graduates(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    sponsor = instance.Sponsor_User
    if created and sponsor:
        if sponsor.user_set.count() >= 2:
            if not User_GraduateList.objects.filter(User=sponsor).exists():
                User_GraduateList.objects.create(User=sponsor)

class GraduateUser(models.Model):
    User = models.ForeignKey(User_GraduateList, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        suser = '{0.User}'
        return suser.format(self)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_graduates(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    sponsor = instance
    if created and sponsor:
        print("1")
        if sponsor.user_set.count() >= 6:
            print("2")
            if not GraduateUser.objects.filter(User=sponsor).exists():
                print("3")
                GraduateUser.objects.create(User=sponsor)
```

I dont receive any error

NOTE: This Question is not quite similar to my previous question [Django Signal post_save()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60559305/django-signal-post-save)

**UPDATE**

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def create_graduates(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        sponsor = instance
        print(instance)
        if created and sponsor:
            print("1")
            if sponsor.user_set.count() >= 6:
                print("2")
                if not GraduateUser.objects.filter(User=sponsor).exists():
                    print("3")
                    GraduateUser.objects.create(User=sponsor)
```

when i try to insert data in table user,

I receive in the cmd or terminal, the id of every new entery and 1

```
 >>new entry
 >>1
```

please read this guys,

if the **User** receive 6 new entry, the first profile saves in **User_GraduateList** remove and save to another table **GraduateUser**

the difference between [Django Signal post_save()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60559305/django-signal-post-save) and this question is Once the system detects that the **User.Sponsor_User**(foreignkey in models **User**) already invited 2 users, that User will automatically save in **User_GraduateList**

**UPDATE AGAIN**

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def im_graduate(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    s = User_GraduateList.objects.filter(id = instance.id).order_by('id')
    graduate = instance
    if created and graduate:
        print(graduate.user_set.count())
        if graduate.user_set.count() == 6:
            if not GraduateUser.objects.filter(User=s).exists():
                GraduateUser.objects.create(User=s)
```

I've try to print(graduate.user_set.count()) the result is always >>0 , it didn't count the New Entry Inserted in **User Table**

Another Example

for every new Entries Insert in **User Table**

```
>>New Entry 1
>>New Entry 2
>>New Entry 3
>>New Entry 4
>>New Entry 5
>>New Entry 6
```

if it reach **New Entry 6** the first Entry that saves in **User_GraduateList Table** remove and save to another table GraduateUser

Comment: Post your output and any errors you're encountering.

Comment: i dont receive any error and output

Comment: If you don't get 1 as output then you're not setting Sponsor_User when creating a User

Comment: add `print('Sponsor: ', sponsor)` right after `instance.Sponsor_User`. What do you get?

Comment: wait mr@Mathias

Comment: I receive the foreignkey of User field and i received print 1 now

Comment: I don't what you've changed to see "1" now. But it means you can debug further. What's the output of `print(sponsor.user_set.count())` right after `print("1")`.

Comment: I receive '0' mr @Mathias

Comment: @justin you mentioned that this is not similar to your [earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60559305/django-signal-post-save). What is different here? Could you please update the question with what is expected and also the set of commands that you are running to test this.Looking at your model structure, what you are trying to achieve is not really clear. And, it could be that at the end of the day you even need to model it differently.

Comment: @AKS please checked my update question

Comment: Two things: 1) if you are creating a new signal, please use a different name for that. Right now, you are using `create_graduates` name two times. 2). In the second signal where you are creating `GraduateUser`, the `sponsor` is set to `instance` instead of `instance.Sponsor_User` as it was done in the first signal. Please make these changes and test again.

Comment: I just want to count the New Entries in User table by ID

Comment: With your last update you're kinda making a mess. `instance/graduate` is always `True`

Comment: @Mathias do you understand what my problem is? please help me to configure this out.

Comment: I mean I see your problem, but the code is a mess and `things` suddenly work, which did not work before. So as as others mentioned, you con't draw the full picture here, which makes it really hard to help.

Comment: So right now `graduate` is a User instance, why do you call `user_set` on it? According to your naming you may register the signal to `GraduateUser`?

Comment: Or you're doing `graduate.graduateuser_set.count()`, instead of `graduate.user_set.count()`.

Comment: @Mathias do you have a better solution for my problem sir?

Comment: Did you tried all the hints from my last 3 comments?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209862/discussion-between-justin-and-mathias).

Comment: I dont understand sorry, im not really good in Django signal

Comment: @justin Please let me know if I get it correctly. In the previous post, if a user has invited 2 users, you wanted to save the user in `User_GraduateList` and now if the user has invited 6 new users, you want to save it in `GraduateUser`. Additionally, you also want to delete that user from `User_GraduateList`. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @AKS you got it

Comment: @justin Please check the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I have [understood](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60540608/django-signals-post-save-that-use-foreign-key?noredirect=1#comment107564138_60540608), I will try to answer:

First of all, I think in `GraduateUser`, the foreign key relationship should be on `User` and not on `User_GraduateList`

```
class GraduateUser(models.Model):
    User = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
```

Next, let's do everything in one signal. We don't need two signals for this purpose.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_graduates(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    sponsor = instance.Sponsor_User
    if created and sponsor:
        user_count = sponsor.user_set.count()
        if 2 <= user_count < 6:
            if not User_GraduateList.objects.filter(User=sponsor).exists():
                User_GraduateList.objects.create(User=sponsor)
        elif user_count >= 6:
            User_GraduateList.objects.filter(User=sponsor).delete()
            if not GraduateUser.objects.filter(User=sponsor).exists():
                GraduateUser.objects.create(User=sponsor)
```

Comment: if the ""User"" receive 6 new entry, the first profile saves in """User_GraduateList""" remove and save to another table ""GraduateUser""

Comment: Did you change the `GraduateUser` model as proposed in the solution?