# Django Signal post_save()

Tags: django, django-models

Once the system detects that you already invited 2 users, your profile will automatically save in graduate list

please see this picture, as example:

[image]

this is the table of graduate list.

[image]

as you can see in the picture,  **Joe Dio** has already invited 2 users (**miro** and **justin**), (you can see it in the **Sponsor user**)

I hope you can help me to figure it out using django signal, thanks in advance :)

i wish the example I made had you understood what i wanted to get

this is my models.py

```
class User(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True,blank=True)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    middlename = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)

    birthday = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    Email  =  models.CharField(max_length=500,null=True,blank=True)
    Sponsor_User = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True, null=True)

class User_GraduateList(models.Model):
    User = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        suser = '{0.User}'
```

**UPDATE** this is the answer of mr @AKS

```
class User_GraduateList(models.Model):
    User = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def create_graduates(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        sponsor = instance.Sponsor_User
        if created and sponsor:
            if sponsor.user_set.count() >= 2:
                if not User_GraduateList.objects.filter(User=sponsor).exists():
                    User_GraduateList.objects.create(User=sponsor)
```

it didnt work.

Comment: I think you forgot to send any value in a dictionary from view to html page.

Comment: nope mr@MajidA  ..

Comment: Why your `render` is in the `for loop`. It has to be outside of that block. Unless it will iterate only one time.

Comment: wrong typo sorry

Comment: Is `Sponsor_User` set during creation of the invited user or can it be linked later too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class User_GraduateList(models.Model):
    User = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_graduates(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    sponsor = instance.Sponsor_User
    if created and sponsor:
        if sponsor.user_set.count() >= 2:
            if not User_GraduateList.objects.filter(User=sponsor).exists():
                User_GraduateList.objects.create(User=sponsor)
```

For reading purposes, I have nested the if conditions. If you feel comfortable, you can join then using `and`.

The solution above is based on the assumption that we only want to do this when a new user is created. If the sponsor user can be set later, the `created` check can be removed from the first condition.

Also, looking at the models, I think it will be best to have a one to one relationship between the `User_GraduateList` and `User` model.

Comment: where do i put this on my code? under the User_GraduateList?

Comment: Yes, and you will need to import the necessary things.

Comment: it doesnt work mr@AKS, I already import the receiver and post_save, im pretty sure i misunderstood your code or your answer doenst work

Comment: Just saying doesn't work doesn't help in anyway. Are you getting any errors or did you try to debug that exactly why it doesn't work as expected?

Based on your updated question, the method shouldn't be put inside User_GraduateList. When you asked under, I meant below the model but on the same level not as a method for the model.

Comment: i didnt get any error i already debug it and no error exist, ive try to put print('ssss') after if created and sponsor: it did not print in the terminal

Comment: Please check this [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/signals/#connecting-to-signals-sent-by-specific-senders). It shows that the signal receiver should be defined at the module level. It shouldn't be put inside the model.

Comment: I have updated my answer the reflect where you should define the receiver.

Comment: I am not sure. It could be because of two reasons - either you don't have enough points to award a bounty of 100. Or, it hasn't been 24 hours since the bounty was set. You can try it some other day.

Comment: maybe because  it hasn't been 24 hours since the bounty was set, dont worry i will award you as soon as after 24 hours, thanks for the help